# Phase vocoder - synthesis window needed?

Tags: signal-processing, fft, phase, ifft

I've been struggling for a few weeks on a phase vocoder. The ultimate goal is achieving time stretching of a signal. I've been making a lot of progress, but I still have two issues to solve.

**Issue1**: Do I need a synthesis window?.
I take overlapping frames from the input signal (a sine wave) with any hop size (e.g. N/2, N = samples per frame). I apply a Hanning window to the frame and feed the result to FFT.
To achieve time-stretching I perform iFFT and overlap-add the output frames using a different hop size than the one used during analysis.
The problem is that with an output hop factor = 0.5 (hop size = N/2) the output is smooth, but for greater hop-sizes I can hear 'vibrations'. The image shows the output of 8 frames with a hop factor = 1 (zero overlap). It is evident why the sound is *vibrating*. For small hop sizes the frames overlap much more and the sound is smoother. I've read a lot about phase vocoding, **but I don't seem to get how to get a smooth output for large hop sizes. What am I missing?**

[image]

**Issue2**: Phase-correction.
Currently the output sounds worse with phase correction but I'll leave that for another post.

Thanks in advance for taking the time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm an amateur at this, but wouldn't you get a better result if you started with a much bigger overlap, e.g. a "hop size" of N/10 or something like that? Then you'd have more freedom to adjust it on output while still keeping a substantial overlap.

Also, it might pay to adjust the steepness of the window depending on how much you're expanding/compressing time.

Comment: Ohhhh I'm happy now!! After I posted the question I started to think that it would be better to keep the output hop-factor fixed at 0.5 (ensuring always a constant window), and play with the input hop factor. The fact that you're suggesting the same thing tells me this must be the right thing to do. Thank you!